# Google TV Website, stop screensaver

Tags: screen, google-tv, screensaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript code to prevent screensaver from starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504238/javascript-code-to-prevent-screensaver-from-starting)

If a website is left on for an extended amount of time the screensaver pops up, but not on certain web apps like Crackle.  How does one (as the web developer) prevent the screensaver from becoming active while a video on a website is playing?

Answer (score 1):

This is new Flash Player feature. It blocks screensaver when it's playing some media (audio, video).

From [help.adobe.com - Playing video in full-screen mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3_Flex/WS44B1892B-1668-4a80-8431-6BA0F1947766.html):

> Flash Player and AIR allow you to create a full-screen application for
>   your video playback, and support scaling video to full screen.
>
> For AIR content running in full-screen mode, the system screen saver
>   and power-saving options are disabled during play until either the
>   video input stops or the user exits full-screen mode.

Comment: There's some discussion about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702748/how-does-youtube-prevent-the-screensaver-from-showing-up-during-video-playback).

Comment: I found that doc I mentioned. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

As a web developer, you may be interested to know [why this can't be done with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504238/javascript-code-to-prevent-screensaver-from-starting).

If you're interested doing this on Windows, there are a number of implementations and recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463813/programmatically-prevent-windows-screensaver-from-starting) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241222/need-to-disable-the-screen-saver-screen-locking-in-windows-c-net).  These implementations use languages like C++ and C#, which can interact with the Operating System.  From the second link, this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/08/20/9876113.aspx) specifically addresses videos.