# How does Youtube Web App prevents the screen from going to sleep on Safari IOS?

Tags: mobile-safari, vimeo-player

Im working on a project that has a vimeo video embedded with an inframe.

The video plays inline. And it looks good.

However, the screen goes to sleep (obviously how fast it is going to dim off, depends on specific user settings for that particular device).

I understand Dimming Off the screen is entirely an OS responsibility. However, youtube.com web app, accessed from the same safari, they seem to be doing something, because the video keeps playing inline.

Thoughts?

PD: I just put Safari in the title, but needless to say, this is also the behaviour in Chrome.

Comment: Probably by faking mouse events or keyboard events?

Comment: I found the answer here. It's basically the flash player that does it. Not youtube. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730137/1504265

Comment: @VinodBhavnani thanks for the comment. I was asking about safari mobile, not windows, but it is worth a try with the flash player thing.