# In-browser screensaver with Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, addeventlistener, mousemove, screensaver

Context: For a kiosk application, and for out-of-topic reasons (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127724/how-to-allow-the-windows-screensaver-to-start-even-if-the-current-html-page-cont)), I don't rely on the OS screensaver, but rather implement a screensaver in JS : a black modal layer (full width, full height) with a logo appears after 5 minutes of user inactivity.

**Is it sub-optimal (performance-wise) to `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout` in such a way, i.e. for each `mousemove` (this can happends hundreds of times in a few seconds)**: is there a better way to handle this screensaver triggering?

Here is what I use, it works (here the delay is 2 seconds):

```js
var screensaver_task = null;
var start_screensaver = () => {
    document.querySelector(".screensaver-layout").classList.add("hidden");
    if (screensaver_task) {
        clearTimeout(screensaver_task);
        screensaver_task = null;
    }
    screensaver_task = setTimeout(() => { 
        document.querySelector(".screensaver-layout").classList.remove("hidden");
    }, 2 * 1000);
}
document.addEventListener("mousemove", start_screensaver);
document.addEventListener("click", start_screensaver);
start_screensaver();
```

```css
.screensaver-layout { background: black; z-index: 1000; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
Mouse move here and wait 2 seconds...
<div class="screensaver-layout hidden"></div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/what-is-the-debounce-function-in-javascript) and [throttle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078285/simple-throttle-in-javascript) functions

Comment: @Reyno Both of which involve setting up a timeout.

Comment: @Reyno Yes I was thinking about using debouncing, but only if necessary, do you think it is here?

Comment: Note that having a lengthy timeout is not generally a good idea, assuming your plan in production was to set the timeout for `5 * 60 * 1000`. This is because it can easily get out of sync with the system clock for various reasons - power saving, browser losing focus, etc. A better approach would be to store the time you want the screensaver to appear (ie. now + 5 mins) then use a polling interval at a short delay, 1-5 seconds, and then check if the target time has passed within that handler.

Comment: Or *how to consume more CPU clock for a screen "saver"*.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, that's precisely what I wanted to avoid! :)

Comment: @Reyno If I use debouncing, I'll end up managing two setTimeout timers, do you see a clean solution with this method?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do as little work as possible in a `mousemove` handler.

Since I expect you don't need the screen saver to start *exactly* 2 seconds (or whatever) after the last move, I'd just have a slow `interval` running all the time that checks whether it's been enough time since the last mouse move, like so:

```js
let lastMouseTime = 0;
let screensaverRunning = false;

function updateRunning(flag) {
  screensaverRunning = flag;
  document
    .querySelector(".screensaver-layout")
    .classList.toggle("hidden", !screensaverRunning);
}

setInterval(() => {
  if (!lastMouseTime) return;
  if (!screensaverRunning) {
    if (+new Date() - lastMouseTime >= 2000) {
      updateRunning(true);
    }
  }
}, 1000);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
  lastMouseTime = +new Date();
  if (screensaverRunning) {
    updateRunning(false);
  }
});
```

```css
.screensaver-layout {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Mouse move here and wait approximately 2 seconds...
<div class="screensaver-layout hidden"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution with a `debounce` function that takes two callbacks, one to run at the start and one that runs at the end.

```js
const debounce = (start, end, ms = 500) => {
  let timerId;
  let started = false;

  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timerId);

    // Execute on startup
    if (!started) {
      start(...args);
      started = true;
    }

    // Execute when debounced finished
    timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      end(...args);
      started = false;
    }, ms);
  };
};

const debounceStarted = () => {
  document.querySelector(".screensaver-layout").classList.add("hidden");
}

const debounceEnded = () => {
  document.querySelector(".screensaver-layout").classList.remove("hidden");
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", debounce(debounceStarted, debounceEnded, 2000));
```

```css
.screensaver-layout {
  background: black;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="screensaver-layout hidden"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just record the last time you saw *any* interactive event, and have a screensaver "thread" that checks the last event time and acts accordingly.

```html
<style>
  #screensaver {
    display: none
  }
  
  .has-screensaver #screensaver {
    display: block
  }
</style>

<div id="screensaver">screensaver</div>

<script>
  const INTERACTIVE_EVENTS = [
    'mousedown',
    'mousemove',
    'touchstart',
    'scroll',
    'wheel',
    'keydown',
    // @TODO anything else?
  ];

  const SCREENSAVER_TIMEOUT = 3000


  window.onload = () => {

    let lastEventTime = new Date

    function screenSaver() {
      let elapsed = new Date - lastEventTime
      document.body.classList.toggle(
        'has-screensaver',
        elapsed > SCREENSAVER_TIMEOUT)
      setTimeout(screenSaver, 100)
    }

    INTERACTIVE_EVENTS.forEach(e =>
      window.addEventListener(e,
        () => lastEventTime = new Date()))

    screenSaver()

  }
</script>
```